# Como manipular o conteúdo XML utilizando Spring MVC?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

Preciso consultar dados no formato xml utilizando SOAP e gravar estes dados no banco de dados oracle, como posso fazer isso utilizando Spring MVC?

Comment: tutorial oficial https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Comment: Tem algum link com vídeo aulas ensinando?